# throw Error ('Data source number +h+ is undefined) alasql

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, bots, alasql

It works on jsFiddle but when I deploy my code and run it crashes.
What could be the problem.

```
var res = alasql('SELECT top 5 price, sitedetails->0->latestoffers->0->seller as seller, sitedetails->0->latestoffers->0->availability as availability, sitedetails->0->latestoffers->0->price as price, sitedetails->0->latestoffers->0->isactive as isactive, sitedetails->0->url as url, brand, name, model, description, images, features from ?',[tmp.results]);
            console.log("Results of query:\n" + res);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2c8njgqw/66/#&togetherjs=2TL07FQov1

[Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbWHI.png)
thanks in advance

Comment: "it crashes" - please describe more. See the an improved jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/2c8njgqw/67/ - I cant see any data with "sitedetails"